# DateTime Format for SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, datetime, parameters

ASP.NET form posts date like this date= 30.11.2013 and then I want to use this date in

```
select statement ( ....SqlCommand("select * from ** where PostedDate= @date)  )
```

But SQL Server date accepts datetime like this'2013-11-01 16:00:00.000' could you give me any advice please?

Comment: Why does your ASP.NET form post a string in some regional and ambiguous format? Why isn't it just a datetime value?

Answer (score 2):

Grab the date as a `DateTime` object in C# and send it to sql using a parameter. Something like

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.Parse(date);
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@date", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
param.Value = myDate;
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to convert the date you receive from the form ,
use
DateTime.Parse(string)